# Javascript Duvida Simples

Tags: javascript

Alguém poderia me ajudar nesse teste não estou entendendo referente a criar uma terceira variável para armazenar a atribuícao de A = B e B e = A
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Sua pergunta parece ter alguns problemas e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a melhor por causa disto. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá,

A terceira variável que diz aí, é uma variável temporária, que mantém o valor de A, para que não seja perdido quando substituir pelo valor de B.

É algo mais ou menos assim (Lembrando que o código não está completo).

```
...
var numeroA = 30;
var numeroB = 45;
var temporaria = numberoB;
numeroB = numeroA;
numeroA = temporaria;
...
```

Comment: Tentei fazer nessa forma tmb, mais ele retorna erro: solution.js:13
var resultado = numberoB; ReferenceError: numberoB is not defined

Comment: Consegui, resolver lendo oque vc disse e o que o rapaz de baixo tmb citou obrigado deu certo. 
RESPOSTA: var numeroA = 30;
var numeroB = 45;
var temp = numeroA;
numeroA = numeroB;
numeroB = temp;

Answer (score -1):

Na sua solução todas as variáveis receberam o valor da ultima atribuição (numeroA),
por isso numeroB ficou correta pq tanto ela quanto todo resto recebeu o valor e numeroA que era 30.
além da sujestão do Marcos, você também pode fazer um array para receber o valor das 2.
Assim:

```
var numeroA = 30;
var numeroB = 45;
var numeros = [numeroA ,numeroB ];
numeros.reverse();
[numeroA ,numeroB ] = numeros;
```

Para você entender, eu passei o valor de A e B para numeros sendo assim numeros ficou como [30,45], depois eu usei a função reverse para inverter os valores do array numeros dai passou a ser assim [45,30], depois eu desestruturei os valores de numeros nas variaveis A e B de acordo com a ordem que coloquei elas perante numeros, logo numeroA recebe o valor da primeira posição de numeros e numeroB recebe o valor da segunda posição de numeros, mais complexo mas é válido para conhecimento.